# Want to make a program that it will keep doing till it gets the answer 1 of the input number's cubic root. What changes should i make?

Tags: python

it's becoming infinite loop. Please help. I want to make this program to get cubic root of a number that a user inputs. and how many times i need to cubic root the answers till i get 1.

```
number = float(input("Type your number: "))
steps = 0
croot = number ** 1. / 3
answer = croot ** 1. / 3
while answer != -10000:
  number = answer
  steps += 1
  croot = number ** 1. / 3

  if answer == 1.0:
    break
  print(steps)
```

Comment: It is not clear what your `while` loop does. You never modify `answer` so it will obviously be an endless loop. Also note that `x ** 1.0 / 3` is not the same as `x ** (1.0 / 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are entering an infinite loop is because you never redefine `answer` therefore, you will never exit your while loop because `answer` is always the same.

However, we can heavily simplify your code as well:

```
steps = 0
answer = 0
while answer != 1.0:
  steps += 1
  number = float(input("Type your number: "))
  answer = number ** (1.0 / 3)
  print(steps)
```

First, we start with default values of `steps` and `answer`. From what I can see, there is no need to define a third variable, `croot`.

We are running the loop **while** the cube root, `answer`, is not `1.0`. Therefore, there is no need for an if statement when we can simply make `answer != 1.0` our condition for the while loop.

When we are inside the while loop, we increment the value of `steps` and take in user input. Then, we can define `answer` and print out `steps`. This will allow for the loop to break if `answer = 1.0`.

I hope this helped answer your question! Please let me know if you need any further clarification or details :)

Answer (score 0):

Your croot and answer are supposed to raise to the power of (1/3)? And you are using the same value for number in the `while` loop? Maybe this is what you want?

```
croot = number ** (1. / 3)
answer = croot ** (1. / 3)
while answer != -10000:
    number = answer
    steps += 1
    croot = number ** 1. / 3
    answer = croot ** (1. / 3)

    if answer == 1.0:
        break
    print(steps)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Some code should be inside the loop.
   You only modify `answer` once, so is should be added to the loop as well.

   ```
    answer = number ** 1.0/3
   ```
2. Some code is redundant:
   `croot` is an unneeded variable
3. `while True` is preferred for a loop

   After corrections:

   ```
   number = float(input("Type your number: "))
   steps = 0
   while True:
     answer = number ** 1/3
     number = answer

     if answer <= 1.0:
       break
     steps += 1
     print(steps)
   ```